# Null при при передаче файла на сервер через Ajax форму ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой при передаче файла (изображения) на сервер, всё вроде бы ничего когда передается единственный файл с единственной формы на странице, но  когда пытаюсь сделать несколько форм, данные не передаются. Всего на форме 7 изображений (только не кидайте камнями, особенности базы) каждое из которых характеризуется полями:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase Data { get; set; }
    public byte[] Img { get; set; }
    public string MIMEType { get; set; }
}
```

Img - чтобы забирать из базы, Data - пытаюсь получать из форм

Обобщающая вьюха:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    <div id="image-@i">
        @Html.Partial("EditImage", new Image() { Id = Model.Imgs[i-1], Number = i, ProductId = Model.Id })
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
}
```

собственно EditImage:

```
@model Image

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditImage", "Product", null, new AjaxOptions() 
             { 
                 Url = "/Product/EditImage", 
                 HttpMethod = "Post", 
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                 UpdateTargetId = "image-" + Model.Number.ToString() 
             }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MIMEType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Number)

    <div class="mini-image left">
        <img src="@Url.Action("Image", "Home", new { Id = Model.Id })" />
    </div>

    <input type="file" name="Data" />

    <input id="ok-@Model.Number" type="submit" value="Изменить"/>
    <input id="del-@Model.Number" type="reset" value="Удалить"/>
}
```

На первой же строчке экшена в контроллере стоит брекпоинт, при дебаге передаются и ProductId, и Number, а вот само изображение отказывается

UPDATE: поудалял из кода всякие onclick, которые висели для визуальных эффектов, так код читается лучше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо разбирать файлы пришедшие с формой отдельно от параметров формы, затем ассоциировать записи пришедшие с формой с файлами.

Посмотрите, что приходит в данных параметрах на стороне сервера (контроллера):

```
System.IO.Stream stream = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0].InputStream : Request.InputStream;
```

Если файлы есть, вам крупно повезло. Если нет, покапайте еще, или..., конечно, есть другой, интересный вариант, но не элегантный и не с поддержкой в старых браузерах.

**Update:** Для асинхронной загрузки файлов к товарам можно использовать уже готовый js модуль, например: [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Comment: пробовал, там 0. поделитесь не элегантным вариантом, пожалуйста, уже не знаю куда деваться

Comment: **Сначала**: Почему бы вам не воспользоваться загрузкой изображений после добавления товара?... так стоп.. смотрю на ваш код... товар у вас уже добавлен! Проблем вообще нет! Подключите уже готовый модуль для ajax загрузки файлов, например jQuery-File-Upload или любой другой и загружайте хоть пачками, хоть перетаскиванием мыши.
 
У вас изображение в чем хранится (просто интересно)?

    src="@Url.Action("Image", "Home", new { Id = Model.Id })"